# Proper way to document what the closing tag is closing

Tags: html, documentation, w3c

In my webpage, I have a lot of `div`s. I've been finding it very difficult, when seeing a few lines of closing tags - `</div>` s - to know which `<div>` it's closing.

I suppose I can use HTML comments to document which closing `div` corresponds to which opening `div`. I would use the `div` id in a comment near the closing tag.

But I feel like there must be a better way, despite the fact that Google turned up nothing relevant for my searches.

What is the best way to document closing `div`s?

Comment: Have you tried indenting your code to represent at which level the div is closing?

Comment: Yes, I do that, but it is often difficult to see the whole picture at once. It's a pain to scroll all the way and try to remember exactly how many indents your closing tag was at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a community held *'best way'*. But I often use html comments and I know a lot of other developers do too, looking at the source code on well formatted sites will show you its an often used technique.

```
<div id="some-id">
   ... Some Content ...
</div><!-- some id -->
```

This will read nicer if you have indentation for each of your block level elements.

Comment: This is pretty much the *only* way. You can’t put anything extra in the end tag itself, by HTML syntax. Whether this is useful is debatable. Comments are risky, it’s easy to cause errors e.g. by closing comments properly. But short, simple comments like this are probably OK.